# When a Render Pass decides what textures it needs, how are shaders written?

Tags: rendering, rendertargets

I am studying render graph architectures (I've seen the Frostbite presentation).
A RenderPass has outputs (i.e. textures you draw to) and inputs.

How are these inputs bound to the internal pipeline ?
Lets say I have an AO Pass and it has Normals and Depth as the input.
Do I just bind the texture to a register and that's it and sample it?
What about the actual shaders (for drawing geometry) that also use textures?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. In all cases, you are the one who writes and binds the shader you want to use for drawing. What obstacle have you encountered here that we can help you overcome?

Comment: @DMGregory It's purely theoretical.
The point of a render graph is to have a flexible Frame rendering.
I should be able to dis/enable passes even at runtime.
How can this be achieved when shaders need to know which textures it uses?

Comment: You write code that associates a set of shaders or drawing operations with each pass. When you disable a pass, you skip binding and drawing with those shaders. You might want to take a look at how some free-to-try engines like Unity or Unreal do this to get a feel for approaches that have scaled well, then ask here if you have a specific question about implementing your own version.